# How does one load XML column into another table?

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have a temp table called #printer with a column called XML_LOAD that is of type XML (screenshot of field attached)

[image]

How does one load the field #printer.XML_LOAD into another table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution than this

```
    if object_id('tempdb..#init') is not null  begin drop table #init end;
    SELECT PL.RECORD_ID, PL.PRINTER_LEVELS
    INTO #INIT
    FROM PRINT_LOG PL
    WHERE PL.INSTANT_OF_PRI_DTTM BETWEEN '2018-04-26 00:00:00.000' and '2018-04-27 00:00:00.000'


    SELECT F1.RECORD_ID,
     F1.PRINTER_LEVELS,
     O.splitdata 
    FROM
     (
     SELECT *,
     cast('<X>'+replace(F.PRINTER_LEVELS,':','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as         xmlfilter from #INIT F
     )F1
     CROSS APPLY
     ( 
     SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(254)') as splitdata 
     FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)) O
```